# Angular: Not preselecting dropdown value (ControlValueAccessor)

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have a very strange issue. I'm implementing a dropdown-wrapper component, which should only mimic the behaviour of a select.

However, Whenever I pass in something into `selectedOption` (in my case I'm passing in `item-3` (which is the value of the third item), it's not preselecting that item.

The select shows up only with no label. Somehow it seems like the value doesn't match the value, but it does :///

`dropdown.component.html`

```html
<select class="dropdown" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option disabled>{{ placeholder }}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [selected]="value === item.value" [value]="item.value">{{ item.label }}</option>
</select>
```

`dropdown.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class DropdownComponent
  implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnChanges
{
  @Input() selectedOption?: string;
  @Input() items: DropdownOption[] = [];
  @Input() placeholder = 'Select an option';

  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onChange = (value: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  field = '';

  constructor() {}
  // sets the value used by the ngModel of the element
  set value(val: string) {
    this.field = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!!this.selectedOption) {
      this.writeValue(this.selectedOption);
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (!!changes['selectedOption']?.currentValue) {
      this.writeValue(changes['selectedOption'].currentValue);
    }
  }

  // This will will write the value to the view if the the value changes occur on the model programmatically
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  // When the value in the UI is changed, this method will invoke a callback function
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // When the element is touched, this method will get called
  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }
}
```

Also, the second issue is:

Whenever I select something in the dropdown, it throws the following error:
[image]

Dows anybody have an idea? I would really appreciate help :)

@Update:
The component is used in this way:

```html
<app-dropdown [selectedOption]="'item-3'" [items]="items"
```

whereas items is:

```js
const items: DropdownItem[] = [
    {
      label: 'Item 1',
      value: 'item-1',
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 2',
      value: 'item-2',
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 3',
      value: 'item-3',
    },
  ];
```

Comment: and how is `app-dropdown` being used in the other components? if you are using reactive forms approach, make sure to add `formControlName` into app-dropdown

Comment: I just updated my post and added an implementation of `app-dropdown`

Comment: in `app-dropdown` you are sending `selectedValue`, it should be `selectedOption`

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. Since I re-typed it here. In my code it was correct - still doesn't work unfortunately :/